# After joining two tables, returns only single result in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
if($slug === FALSE){
     $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
     $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
     $query = $this->db->get('posts');
     return $query->result_array();
 }
```

I have three posts in my table but the result I get are only 1. This is the issue I am facing after joining the two tables (categories and posts)

SQL code that is getting executed:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM `posts` 
   JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `post`.`category_id` 
   ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Hard to say anything other than an educated guess without actually seeing a data sample from your tables. If I had to guess, either the posts reference to a category that doesn't exist, or the categories are not being referenced at all in the posts. Inner joins only output what matches every clause you stated. Try using left join and see what changes. You'll be able to figure out what's wrong from there

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your posts have no categories defined. The foreign key field must be set if you want to do an inner join. You are only getting posts which have categories here.
Otherwise you can get posts with no categories using a left join.

Comment: Foreign keys are not needed for joins of any kind. I assume you mean that the fields being used to join (`categories.id=posts.category_id` in this case) must exist on both tables.